# Revert whole Dropbox folder to previous state (Packrat)

Tags: dropbox

I'm using Dropbox's Packrat feature that stores all previous versions of a file, and allows me to restore a deleted file.

Is there a way to restore a complete folder to a previous state, for example 1. May 2014?

I could do it by going through all files in the folder and restoring them to the last change before 1. May 2014. This would be a huge manual task in a large folder.

**Is there a better way? Maybe a Dropbox extension app?**

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052897/revert-all-files-in-a-folder) - it should be on here - I'll flag it.

Answer (score 1):

dropbox-restore

Restore any dropbox folder to a previous state. If a file did not exist at the specified time, it will be deleted.

https://github.com/clark800/dropbox-restore