# How to rollback an entire folder on dropbox?

Tags: windows, dropbox, restore

Is it possible to rollback an entire folder on dropbox? Because sometimes I tend to change a lot of files in the folder, so, rollback-ing each file individually is not convenient.

If it's possible, how to do it?

Thanks.

(I'm a windows user btw)

Comment: Requests for product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Service recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: @CharlieRB changed

Comment: @Ramhound changed

Comment: Are you asking to do the same as this question? [Revert whole Dropbox folder to previous state (Packrat)](http://superuser.com/q/797589/97028)

Comment: @CharlieRB yes. But i'm not sure how to use Dropbox-Restore properly. Last time I tried, it fails

Comment: @CharlieRB do you know where to type it the sudo dropbox pip thing?

Comment: No, I don't. Sorry.

Comment: @CharlieRB  It is a Python script, so you need to install Python and PIP (which is a kind of package management system for Python modules). Just install both (google "Anaconda" if you don't know how) and run "pip install dropbox" from a command prompt with administrator rights.

Comment: @CharlieRB it half worked. where do i need to type in the `restore.py` thing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Python.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24036435/413180) - That is, you can contact Dropbox support and they should be able to roll back for you.